# How can I fix "Connection timed out" when connecting to a server after watching youtube or taxing my computer

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a major issue that just popped out of nowhere: After I watch Youtube or do intensive activity on my computer, when trying to connect to my favorite server I get the error

> java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information: play.opcraft.net/31.220.14.118:25565

I have searched on Tom's Hardware and the Minecraft Forums for common solutions like adding inbound UDP and TCP rules for port 25565 but to no avail. Others said turn the chunk render down to a low setting, but that also didn't work. I'm honestly out of tricks and don't know how to solve it.

This just started happening about a week ago and its never done it before. I've tried to reset the `.minecraft` folder and it didn't work.

The only thing that *does* work is restarting my computer, which is getting annoying every day. If someone has a solution, can you please help me.

Comment: Sounds like something else you're running has a memory leak, eating up the available memory on your computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what it was. I was going to update the post later. It was the adobe flash 19 update. I reverted back to 18 and it's all good.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things that come to mind - but this is really an issue that needs to be troubleshooted. Here are a few things you can try in order to fix this problem.

One possibility is that your internet service provider or hardware is throttling you. Try running a test on speedtest.net before watching a YouTube video and after (while experiencing the issue). If it's the internet that slows down it could be your connection or a faulty router/network card/modem (possibly overheating). Please update your question with the results of these tests.

Another possibility is that your computer is running dangerously low on memory (specifically RAM). YouTube videos get buffered by your browser and eat up loads of RAM. I find that Google Chrome is a huge culprit of eating up lots of memory and not freeing it until at least a few minutes after it's closed. Please let us know how much memory your computer has. Again, do a test before watching a YouTube video and after (while experiencing the issue) and post the amount of free memory available. You can check how much memory your computer is using from the task manager (ctrl + shift + escape).